# Is there any better way to run this query?

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE,
    b.SID,
    b.PID,
    a.DateCreated,
    a.Batch,
    b.Mrp
FROM t1 a INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.SID, a.PID, Max(a.MRP) AS Mrp
    FROM t1 a
    WHERE SID IN ('14' , '142', '1420')
    GROUP BY a.SID , a.PID
) b
ON a.SID = b.SID AND a.PID = b.PID AND a.Mrp = b.Mrp
```

Comment: You are doing a self join and I don't see any obvious way to make a dramatic improvement.

Comment: We cant answer this without knowing the table structure and an explain output, What do you mean with "Is there any better way to  run this query"? Do you mean better SQL or performance? For SQL probably  not you need this derived table and inner join to be sure you select the correct data for `a.DateCreated` and `a.Batch`  For performance you need an covering index on SID, PID, MRP  like this `KEY(SID, PID, MRP)` that should give better performance derived table and inner join

Comment: Probably not! But Provide the explain and proper DDLs for the relevant tables. Removing the inverted commas will help very, very, very fractionally. Also, selecting all columns from a seems more intuitive to me - but I doubt it affects performance

Comment: i mean to say better optimized query and better solution to get the data correctly